# Как подключить bluetooth наушники к arduino?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

У меня есть потребность в звуковой передаче данных человеку, и в данном случае лучше всего подходит подключение беспроводных bluetooth наушников к плате.

Arduino просто как пример. Если вы знаете другие платформы для разработки (ESP32, STM32), которые можно запрограммировать на Arduino IDE, и сопутствующие модули, которые лучше подходят для данной задачи, то можете их и советовать.

Нужно чтобы вне зависимости от модели bluetooth наушников, они могли подключится к данной плате и проигрывать на них звук с SD карты. И желательно решение в низком ценовом диапазоне.

Comment: esp32  думаю подойдет